# background does not show in processing

Tags: processing

```
PImage bg;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  bg = loadImage("bg.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  background(bg);
}
```

The code does not show in processing javascript mode nor processing.js. The image is the same size as the size()
Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Javascript you need to preload the image with `@pjs`. So your code should be like the following:

```
/* @pjs preload="bg.jpg"; */

PImage bg;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  bg = loadImage("bg.jpg");
}
```

And it will still work if you add it in draw as well:

```
void draw() {
  background(bg);
}
```

Check out the documentation here: http://processingjs.org/reference/background_/

Make sure you drag and drop your image on the sketch window so the image gets added to the data folder by Processing. Sometimes if you don't do that, Processing doesn't actually see the image even if you manually put it in the data folder of the sketch.

For Java mode the `@pjs` is not required though, however since its a comment Java will ignore it anyway. You can always switch the mode to Java just to make sure all the images are being added and it actually works properly before sending it over to your browser.

Comment: You are good! The problem is generated from the fact that I did not drag and drop my images to sketch window!